# While Loop Within While Loop, inner only running once PHP

Tags: php, while-loop

I am trying to create a while loop with a while loop inside. The outer while loop moves through a simple array echoing out the months in a year. The inner while loop is connected to the database and echoes out the rows. Now the inner loop is only working once.

I have looked at ([Inner While Loop only run once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9487623/inner-while-loop-only-run-once)) and a few others, I have also tried mysqli_data_seek($variable, 0) to reset the inner while loop. But because I am a noob I cannot figure this out. My simplified code is below.

```
<div>
    <?php $year = date("Y");
    $months = array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"); 
    $i = 0;
    while($i <= (count($months) - 1)) :?>
    <?php $j = $i + 1; ?>
    <p><?php echo $months[$i]; ?> <?php echo $year; ?></p>
        <?php while($row = $company_aircraft->fetch_assoc()) :?>
            <div id="a<?php echo $row['id']; ?>m">
                <p><span id="aircraftID<?php echo $row['id']; ?>-month<?php echo $j; ?>"></span></p>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Put each while into another function and have an easier life

Comment: Sorry bub could you show me an example.

Comment: So have you applied the, mysqli_data_seek($company_aircraft, 0) after the first 'endwhile'? You want to reset the mysqli pointer after the inner loop each time.

Comment: Are you not running into an infinite loop?

Comment: check your `sql statement` and be sure to echo the `mysqli_num_rows` to get the exact number of rows affected and tag me later.